# Android listview onclick listener not working.

Tags: java, android, list, listview

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code. I had been using if fine for days and haven't changed it, i even copied and pasted code from github when it was definitely working. I have now stripped back all my code and just made a simply click on the list view. first I was only getting it to respond to with a position of 0 in the list view now i am getting no response

Please tell me its something stupid that I a missing

Here is the relevant code

```
public class AdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ArrayList<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
            //set the context sp we can use firebase
    //        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
            optionList.add("VIEW DRIVERS");
            optionList.add("DESIGNATE A DRIVER");
            optionList.add("LOG OUT");
            listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(AdminActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, optionList);
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        }
```

and the onclick

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Driver d = driverList.get(position);

        Toast.makeText(this,"Getting in here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("Getting in here");

        if(position == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"0",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else if(position == 1) {

            Toast.makeText(this,"DESIGNATE A DRIVER ACTIVITY 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else if(position == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"GOODBYE 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can't you just set a breakpoint in the beginning of onItemClick() to check what's going on there?

Comment: Its not even making it into the onItemClick() because it is not printing the sytem.out.print i have placed at the start of it?

Comment: I just realised it was the object I was declaring at the start of the onclick was stopping me here. Thats too stupid of me to bother putting an answer for i reckon lol

Answer (score 0):

The Driver object created in the ListView was trying to retrieve from a list that previously had multiple objects in it. Because this list was coming from firebase it had not been throwing up an obvious error. That is why the same code was working previously.